# Get Name, Mark of persons with distinct Mark

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

I am pretty new to SQL and trying to understand the basics. I want to get "name" and "mark" of all persons having distinct mark but couldn't write a query for that. Any help is appreciated.

I tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT mark
FROM (
  SELECT name as 'Name', mark
  FROM student
)
ORDER BY mark;
```

This will only get me the distinct marks but not name.

Table Columns - `name`, `mark`, `gender`.

Note: Two persons can have same name.

Comment: could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: what is `mark`? You don't indicate that as a column in your Table Columns

Comment: @dfundako Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas I have added sqlite but the question got automatically edited and the tag has been removed. Re-added again

Comment: The tags were removed because you used both MySql and SQLite. MySql is not the same as SQLite.

Comment: @forpas Thanks. I have updated the tags. Can you now help me with the query?

Comment: What do you mean by "having a distinct mark"?

Comment: having a unique mark. Suppose if you assume distinct "last name" in place of "mark" it would be easier to understand. All student name, lastname with distinct lastname. eg ---> (hem, kumar), (hema, kumar), (john, doe) I want to return (hem, kumar), (john, doe) as (hem, kumar) is the first distinct one appearing in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT MAX(name) AS Name, mark
FROM student
GROUP BY mark
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, this query also didn't work. Some records were missing in the result. I have a record with columns (id, name, class, mark, gender) as (1, John Deo, Four, 75, female) but in the result I didn't get this record.

Comment: @Hem then either you are doing something wrong or you did not explain exactly what you need. The condition `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` guarantees that only marks that exist only once are returned.

Comment: Columns I have in db (id, name, class, mark, gender) for simplicity I have taken out id, class in question. And what I want is all the (names, marks) of students having unique marks. For suppose (john, 75, M), (hem, 65, F), (john, 80, F), (abc, 80, F) I want to return  ---> (john, 75), (hem, 65), (john, 80)

Comment: @Hem Why do you want  (john, 80) in the results since there is also (abc, 80, F)?

Comment: To get the first distinct one. I may be wrong in my question or way of thinking. Correct me if I'm wrong in some way.

Comment: @Hem there is no first and last in a table unless there is a column that denotes the order of the rows. Also, this has nothing to do with the requirement as you describe it in your question. If your requirement is different you can ask a new question where you explain what you want with sample data and expected results.